# Exchange Server 2013 Recipient Address Masking

Tags: exchange, exchange-2013

Is it possible in Exchange 2013 to setup email forward and also mask the recipient address. Basically I need to put forward but when the destination receives the email it should not show the original To address.

the scenario is something like this: External emails comes in for fakeID@fakedomain.com and then get forwarded to johnt@mycompany.com

Comment: Based on my knowledge, I'm afraid it cannot be achieved. The only way to forward email without showing the original sender or recipient is to copy email content and then paste it in a new email. Or you can use the traditional method to configure email forwarding. For your reference, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/recipients/user-mailboxes/email-forwarding?view=exchserver-2019

Comment: Hi, is there any updates with your issue?